# Cannot Apply Network Settings to MDT - Cannot hit deployment share

Tags: windows-server-2012-r2, mdt

I can hit my deployment share from any computer on the network, but cannot hit it from the computer I'm trying to image.  I added a step to the Task Sequence "Apply Network Settings," but it seems it is ignoring this and using DHCP somehow.  I made sure to update the deployment share.

When I hit F8 to bring up a command prompt I try a "Net Use" command, but it says "System Error 67 has occurred.  The network name cannot be found."

I'm able to ping the mdtserver using its hostname, but it cannot map/find the share.

Thanks in advance!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So it turned out that for whatever reason the wrong host name was in the bootstrap.ini file.  Once I renamed it to the correct name it started working.